# How to get the checked Checkbox values from GSP to java script

Tags: grails, gsp

Hi I am new to grails and GSP

I have a code like

```
<g:each var="i" in="${typeList}">
    <g:if test="${i != null}">
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="categoryType" id="categoryTypeCB" class="categoryTypeCB" value="${i}">&nbsp;${i}</td>
        </tr>
    </g:if>

</g:each>
```

How to get the values of checked check boxes in java script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use jQuery. Since Grails 2.0 it's provided by default, you just have to add in your gsp template at the end of head tag with following line:

```
<r:require module="jquery" />
```

Or if you do not use resources plugin, include jQuery with following line:

```
<g:javascript library='jquery' />
```

And then in a javascript block go with:

```
<g:javascript>    
    var checkedCheckboxes = $('.categoryTypeCB:checked');

    $.each(checkedCheckboxes, function(index, checkbox) {
        var theValue = checkbox.value;
    });
</g:javascript>
```

The *each* funciton is a loop so you need to handle somehow 'theValue' each iteration. The *checkbox* argument contains the *input* element itself if you need it.

BTW. You shouldn't assign the same id for many inputs. It's incorrect. Id has to be unique for each HTML element among document tree.

Comment: You are welcome. If you find my answer useful please click the green check mark next to it.